# PageRank implementation for Research

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm, pagerank

After reading theory of PageRank algorithm from [this site](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-pagerank) I would like to play with it. 
I am trying to implement this in Java. I mean I would like to play with PageRank in detail (like giving different weights and so on). For this I need to build hyperlink matrix. If I have 1 million nodes then my hyperlink matrix will be 1 million x 1 million size, which causes this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at WebGraph.main(WebGraph.java:6)
```

How can I implement PageRank in Java, is there any way of storing hyperlink matrix?

Comment: Where have you already looked? Have you found any non-open source implementations? Have you considered implementing it yourself? Do you have any preferences for language?

Comment: @acattle I have looked at Jung and WebLA. I would like to focus on theory rather than in implementation. Language preferences: any.

Comment: Have you tried increasing your heap size to get rid of that exception?

Comment: @DanW How can I do that?

Comment: you need a library which is good at storing sparse matrices Matlab has such a library (in c++ I believe) which you could borrow, I believe, and link it in your java code. Increasing the heap size is just a bandage solution unless you deal with small graphs/matrices. Maybe use this in java http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/44st/SparseMatrix.java.html

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a great article to learn about pagerank. I implemented a Perl version from it [here](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ekubina/Graph-Centrality-Pagerank/) to use with [Textrank](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ekubina/Text-Categorize-Textrank/). However, if you want to just learn about pagerank and how the various aspects discussed in the article affect the results (dampening factor, direct or undirected graph, etc.), I would recommend running experiments in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) or [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). If you want to learn how to implement it efficiently, then programming it up from scratch, as you are doing, is best.

Most web graphs (or networks) are very [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), which means most of the entries in the matrix representation of the graph are zero. A common data structure used to represent a sparse matrix is a [hash-map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), where the zero values are not stored. For example, if the matrix was

```
1, 0, 0
0, 0, 2,
0, 3, 0
```

a two dimension hash-map would store only the values for hm(0,0)=1, hm(1,2)=2, and hm(2,1)=3. So in a 1,000,000 by 1,000,000 matrix of a [web graph](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48686-0_1), I would expect only a few million values to be non-zero. If each row averages only 5 non-zero values, a hash-map will use about 5*(8+8+8)*10^6 bytes ~ 115mb to store it (8 for the left int index, 8 for the right int index, and 8 for the double value). The square matrix will use 8*10^6*10^6 ~ 7 terabytes.

Implementing an efficient sparse matrix-vector multiply in Java is not trivial, and there are some already [implemented](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112124729/http://commons.apache.org:80/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/linear/SparseRealMatrix.html) if you don't want to devote time to that aspect of the algorithm. The sparse-matrix multiply is the most difficult aspect to implement of the pagerank algorithm, so after that it gets easier (and more interesting).

Answer (score 4):

Python `networkx` module has a nice implementation of pagerank. It uses scipy/numpy for the matrix implementation. The below two questions on stackoverflow should be enough to get you started.

- [How do weighted edges affect PageRank in networkx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136539/how-to-weighted-edges-affect-pagerank-in-networkx)
- [Networkx: Differences between pagerank, pagerank_numpy, and pagerank_scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040548/networkx-differences-between-pagerank-pagerank-numpy-and-pagerank-scipy)

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

- Use python, not Java: python is an excellent prototyping language, and has available sparse matrices (in scipy) as well as many other goodies.  As others have noted, it also has a pagerank implementation.
- Store your data not all in memory: any type of lightweight database would be fine, for instance sqlite, hibernate, ...
- Work on tiles of the data: if there is a big matrix NxN, break it up into small tiles MxM where M is a fraction of N, that fit in memory.  Combined with sparse matrices this allows you to work with really big N (hundreds of millions to billions, depending on how sparse the data is).

Answer (score 0):

As **Dan W** suggested, **try to increase the heap size**. If you run your Java application from the command line, just add the switch `-Xmx` with the desired heap size. Let's assume you compiled your Java code into a runnable JAR file called `pagerank.jar`, and you want to set your heap size to 512 MB, you would issue the following command:

```
java -jar -Xmx512m pagerank.jar
```

**EDIT:**
But that only works if you don't have that many "pages" ... A 1 Million x 1 Million array is too big to fit into your RAM (1 trillion times * 64 bit double value = 7.27595761 terabytes). You should change your algorithm to load chunks of data from the disk, manipulate it, and store it back to disk.

You could use a graph database like [Neo4j](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo4j) for that purpose.

Comment: I have WebGraph.class, so I ran: java -Xmx2048m WebGraph, but it still gives OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @torayeff: See my edited answer. 1 Million * 1 Million nodes = 1 Trillion cells. If you use a double array (a double is probably 64 bit) that would be more than 7 terabytes, which is probably more than your RAM can handle.

Answer (score 0):

PageRank is performed by Google using the 'Pregel' BSP (really just keywords) framework.

I remembered [Apache Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/) (another Pregel), which includes a version of PageRank in its benchmark package.

[Here's a video about Giraph](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZrqPEIPRe4): it's an introduction, and it specifically talks about handling PageRank.

If that doesn't work:

In Java there is an implementation of Pregel called [GoldenOrb](http://goldenorbos.org/index.html).

Pseudo code for the PageRank algorithm is [here](https://github.com/igrigorik/pregel) (on a different implementation of Pregel).

You'll have to read around BSP, and PageRank to handle the size of data you have.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to store the whole 1000000x1000000 matrix, because most matrix entries will be zero.  Instead, you can (for example) store a list of nonzero entries for each row, and write your matrix functions to use it directly, without expanding it into a full matrix.

This kind of compressed representation is called a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) format, and most matrix libraries have an option to build and work with sparse matrices.

One disadvantage with sparse matrices is that multiplying two of them will result in a matrix which is much less sparse.  However, the PageRank algorithm is designed so that you don't need to do that:  the hyperlink matrix is constant, and only the score vector is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the matrix is sparse you can implement dimensionality reduction like svd,pca,mds or Lsi that includes svd. There is a library to implement this kind of processes which is called Jama. You can find it [here](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)